# arm64 macho store label in register from outside of section

Tags: assembly, arm, apple-m1, arm64

I have the assembly code compiling for Mac m1 (arm64 macho):

```
.text                                                                                                                                                  
.globl main                                                                                                                                            
.p2align        2                                                                                                                                      
main:                                                                                                                                                  
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!                                                                                                                   
        add     x29, sp, 0                                                                                                                                     mov     x2, #6                                                                                                                                 
        adrp    x1, _fmt@PAGE                                                                                                                          
        add     x1, x1, _fmt@PAGEOFF                                                                                                                   
        mov     x0, #1                                                                                                                                 
        adrp    x3, _write@PAGE                                                                                                                        
        add     x3, x3, _write@PAGEOFF                                                                                                                 
        blr     x3                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                       
        mov     w0, #0                                                                                                                                 
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], #16                                                                                                                    
        ret                                                                                                                                            
/* end function main */                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                       
.balign 8                                                                                                                                              
_fmt:                                                                                                                                                  
        .ascii "Hello\n"
```

which fails with:

```
final section layout:
    __TEXT/__text addr=0x100003F88, size=0x00000030, fileOffset=0x00003F88, type=1
    __TEXT/__unwind_info addr=0x100003FB8, size=0x00000048, fileOffset=0x00003FB8, type=22
    __DATA/__data addr=0x100004000, size=0x00000006, fileOffset=0x00004000, type=0
ld: ARM64 ADRP out of range (-4294979584 max is +/-4GB): from main (0x100003F88) to _write@0x00000000 (0x00000000) in 'main' from test.o for architecture arm64
```

<s>I believe this happens because the `_write` instruction references the write syscall which isn't available until link time which means the assembler doesn't know what to put as the address for `_write` and it gets written as `0x00000000`. (Correct me if I am wrong)</s>

I am wrong. (thanks @user3124812)

The annoying part is this doesn't happen if I call `bl _write` without putting it in an register first.

For example:

```
.text                                                                                                                                                  
.globl main                                                                                                                                            
.p2align        2                                                                                                                                      
main:                                                                                                                                                  
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!                                                                                                                   
        add     x29, sp, 0                                                                                                                                     mov     x2, #6                                                                                                                                 
        adrp    x1, _fmt@PAGE                                                                                                                          
        add     x1, x1, _fmt@PAGEOFF                                                                                                                   
        mov     x0, #1                                                                                                                                 
        bl _write                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                       
        mov     w0, #0                                                                                                                                 
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], #16                                                                                                                    
        ret                                                                                                                                            
/* end function main */                                                                                                                                
.data                                                                                                                                                  
.balign 8                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                       
_fmt:                                                                                                                                                  
        .ascii "Hello\n"
```

This works and prints `Hello` followed by a newline.

Why can't I store the label location in a register before printing it? It seems to work with labels in my section

Comment: "(Correct me if I am wrong)", you are wrong in a whole paragraph

Comment: `adrp    x3, _write@PAGE` loads address of that `_write@PAGE` into `x3` register. It has nothing to do with 'instruction reference' or 'syscall'. Linker works after assembler, and assembler itself does not need to know address of `_write...`

Comment: Thanks @user3124812 for the clarification! I edited that paragraph to avoid confusion the question for future readers. I still don't know why
 the error shows `_write@0x00000000` then... Also still curious why I can't write it to that register.

Comment: have you tried something like `ldr x3,=_write` ? You would not need `add     x3, x3, _write@PAGEOFF` after that

Comment: Looks like that give me `terminated by signal SIGBUS (Misaligned address error)`. `objdump -D` gives me `100003f98: c3 00 00 58  ldr x3, 0x100003fb0 <main+0x30>`.

Comment: interestingly if I compile the working version with `bl _write` my `.o` file objdumps `18: 00 00 00 94   bl 0x18 <main+0x18>` and the executable dumps `100003f9c: 04 00 00 94  bl 0x100003fac <_write+0x100003fac>`

Comment: Yeah, fun the `adrp` version `.o` file generates `18: 03 00 00 90   adrp x3, 0x0 <main+0x18>` *visible confusion*

Comment: I'm not sure about the dynamic linking model of macOS, but I suppose it supports symbol interposition and has something similar to a GOT.  In such a case, you cannot directly obtain the address of a symbol.  You have to look up the address in the GOT.  Let me try to make an example for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of symbols that are not defined in the same shared object as the code referencing them are not known.  For this reason, you have to load such addresses from the global offset table (GOT) like this:

```
adrp    x0, _write@GOTPAGE
ldr     x0, [x0, _write@GOTPAGEOFF]
```

This loads the address of `_write` into `x0`.  Such code can also be used for symbols defined in the same shared object as the reference, but in such cases it might be easier to just access them directly.

When you call a function directly with `bl`, the linker makes the call go to the procedure linkage table (PLT) which holds a trampoline going to the actual function.  Hence, direct calls work.