# How to load data by label on Apple Silicon (ARM64)?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

*LDR* doesn't work correctly due Apple's thoughts about security, but how I can load, for example this:

```
.data
.align 4
.mynumber: .quad   0x123456789ABCDEF0
```

I know about ADRP, but I'm not sure that I understand how it works.

I have already done this(ADRP, @PAGE, @PAGEOFF was taken from other sources):

```
.global _start

.text
_start: 
    ADRP    X2, arr1@PAGE
    ADD X2, X2, arr1@PAGEOFF

    mov     X0, #0      // Use 0 return code
    mov     X16, #1     // System call number 1 terminates this program
    svc     #0x80       // Call kernel to terminate the program

.data
.align 4
arr1:   .FILL   10, 4, 0
mynumber:   .quad   0x123456789ABCDEF0
myoctaword: .octa 0x12345678876543211234567887654321
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do it (`adrp` and then `add`).  What is your question?

Comment: @fuz what is PAGE, PAGEOFF then? and why we need adrp and then add? GPT tells me that adrp loads highest part of address and add with PAGEOFF adds lowest

Comment: `adrp` loads a page (4 kB) aligned address relative the current program counter.  `ADD` is used to add the low 12 bit to that page address, giving the correct address of `addr1`. 
 `@PAGE` and `@PAGEOFF` specify the relocation type: the first tells the linker to substitute the address of the page in which the symbol is located, the second tell the linker to substitute the offset within the page.

Comment: @fuz thanks! Your answer helps me to understand

Comment: Related: [Accessing global variables in ARM64 position independent assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75474024)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loading "data by label" works perfectly fine:

```
ldr x0, label

label:
    .8byte 0x0123456789abcdef
```

What doesn't work on Darwin is `ldr x0, =...`, because that's syntactic sugar for this:

```
ldr x0, addrof_label

label:
    .8byte 0x0123456789abcdef
addrof_label:
    .8byte label
```

And since `label` is a statically encoded address, it would need to be rebased by the dynamic linker, which crashes the process when attempted, since the `__TEXT` segment is both mapped as `r-x` and codesigned.

For getting the address of some labels, you can use `adr`:

```
adr x0, label

label:
    .8byte 0x0123456789abcdef
```

But this will only work in a ±1MiB range, and additionally the toolchain will only let you do this within the same segment, i.e. `__TEXT`. For the general case, `adrp+add` is the way to go:

```
adrp x0, label@PAGE
add x0, x0, label@PAGEOFF

.data
label:
    .8byte 0x0123456789abcdef
```

But you can use `.loh AdrpAdd ...` directives to have the linker fix this back up into `adr+nop` if the resulting offset is in range:

```
L1:
adrp x0, label@PAGE
L2:
add x0, x0, label@PAGEOFF
.loh AdrpAdd L1, L2

.data
label:
    .8byte 0x0123456789abcdef
```

The same can be done with `adrp+ldr` if necessary, and likewise `.loh AdrpLdr ...` can turn that into just a PC-relative `ldr` if in range.