# Cant capture user input in simple MacOS assembly program

Tags: macos, assembly, arm64

I'm trying to write a program that would take an input (8 digit) from a user. However, I keep getting a buffer error. I already ran out of ideas.

```
  // Write the prompt to stdout
  _start:
  mov x0, 1            // File descriptor for stdout
  ldr x1, =prompt      // Address of the prompt
  mov x2, 16          // Length of the prompt 
  mov x16, 4  // syscall number for write (write to stdout)
  svc 0                // Call write syscall

  // Read user input
  mov x0, 0            // File descriptor for stdin
  ldr x1, =name_buffer // Buffer to store input
  mov x2, 8           // Maximum number of characters to read
  mov x16, 3  // syscall number for read (read from stdin)
  svc 0                // Call read syscall

  //exit code 
  mov x16, 1  // syscall number for exit
  mov x0, 0
  svc 0             // Call write syscall


 prompt: .asciz "Enter your name: "
 name_buffer: .ds 8  // Allocate space
```

Comment: You don't have a `.section` directive between your code and your buffer, so `name_buffer: .ds 8  // Allocate space` is in the `.text` section: read-only + exec permission.  A read system call will return `EFAULT`, which tells you that memory permission is the problem.  (macOS should have `truss` or `dtrace` or something that can trace system calls of your program.)

Comment: Also don't use `ldr =...` on Darwin. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76318308).

Comment: Thanks for replying. So I added .data before prompt: but still get the same bus error. Do I need to modify the makefile as well?