# Using string constants in Rust inline assembly

Tags: assembly, rust, inline-assembly, arm64

I am trying to execute a `write` syscall using inline assembly in Rust. Basically I'm trying to reproduce [this hello world example](https://github.com/below/HelloSilicon/blob/main/Chapter%2001/HelloWorld.s). I'm trying to pass in a reference to a string slice as my message, but I'm getting the following error which seems to contradict its self:

```
cannot use value of type `*const str` for inline assembly
only integers, floats, SIMD vectors, pointers and function pointers can be used as arguments for inline assembly
```

The code is below, but my questions are:

1. Is there a more suitable sort of pointer than a `*const str`?
2. I'm still in the early days of working with assembly, are there other glaring problems that I'm missing?

```rust
use std::arch::asm;

fn main() {
    let msg = "Hello World!\n";
    let len = msg.len();
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "mov X0,  #1",     // specify stdout
            "adr X1,  {msg}",  // point to message
            "mov X2,  {len}",  // specify message length
            "mov X16, #4",     // specify syscall number for 'write'
            "svc #0x80",       // syscall
            msg = in(reg) msg,
            len = in(reg) len,
       );
    }
}
```

This is running on MacOS v13.6, on an M1 chip (Armv8.5-a).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there is a slight difference between `&str` which is a *wide* reference, `*const str` a *wide* pointer and a thin pointer as required by the assembly. Though the error message could make the requirement for a *thin* pointer clearer. Fortunately there is a method to turn a `&str` into an apropriate pointer unsurprisingly called [`as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_ptr)

```rust
use std::arch::asm;

fn main() {
    let msg_str = "Hello World!\n";
    let len = msg_str.len();
    let msg = msg_str.as_ptr();
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "mov X0,  #1",     // specify stdout
            "adr X1,  {msg}",  // point to message
            "mov X2,  {len}",  // specify message length
            "mov X16, #4",     // specify syscall number for 'write'
            "svc #0x80",       // syscall
            msg = in(reg) msg,
            len = in(reg) len,
       );
    }
}
```

Does get further, but I can't test the arm assembly so it still fails to compile for me.

Comment: Compiles but doesn't assemble or link with `rustc -O --target=aarch64-apple-darwin` https://godbolt.org/z/qPGGY1Ecc - IIRC, `adr` isn't usable across sections on MacOS, you'd need adrp/add as shown in [How to load data by label on Apple Silicon (ARM64)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76316445).  You could just ask for the pointer already in a register, surely?  Or wait, this asm *is* asking for that, but using `adr` instead of `mov`. 
 Also, this is missing clobbers on the registers it writes.

Comment: Yes, good point. Changing `adr` to `mov` compiles and prints the message. And yes, I did forget to include the clobbers for x0, x1, x2, and x16.

Comment: Alternatively, use ASCII strings `b"..."`.