`zsh: invalid system call: ./hello` when running my arm64 assembly on my apple-silicon mac
I'm learning assembly with the arm64 architecture on my M2 mac. I my hello world code (in file hello.s).
hello.s (btw: I removed the comments for readability):
.global _start
.align 4

_start:

    mov     X0, #1
    adr     X1, msg
    mov     X2, #13 
    mov     X16, #4
    svc     #0x80

    mov     X0, #0
    mov     X16, #1
    svc     #0x80

.data
    msg: .ascii "Hello World!\n"

Hello.s assembles perfectly using as hello.s -o hello.o I also tried retyping it as as -arch arm64 -o hello.o hello.s and it returns an object file named hello.o. Then I link the object file as so:
ld -o hello hello.o -lSystem -syslibroot xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path -e _start -arch arm64
It returns an executable file: hello
But the error occurs when I the run the file with ./hello
I get the error message:
zsh: invalid system call  ./hello
I have tried changing the code in the assembly file as I saw in a Youtube video to
.global _start

_start:
        mov x0, #1
        ldr x1, =msg 
        mov x2, #14
        mov x8, #64
        svc #0
        
        mov x0, #0
        mov x8, #93
        svc #0


.data
msg: .ascii"Hello, world!\n"

This still assembled and linked successfully, but gave the same runtime error.
I also tried changing the linking call, but that didn't do anything to fix it (I didn't try every linking possible, mostly because I'm new to assembly and don't understand all of the linking, so this still might be the error).
Please inform me if you need more information.
edit:
I recently tried to assemble in a different shell and I got that I had a Bad system call: 12 from sh-3.2$ ./hello command

HelloWorld.c:
.global _start      
.align 4    

_start: 
    mov X0, #1
    adrp X1, helloworld@page
    add X1, X1, helloworld@pageoff 
    mov X2, #13    
    mov X16, #4
    svc #0x80

    mov     X0, #0      
    mov     X16, #1     
    svc     #0x80       

    .data
helloworld:      
    .ascii  "Hello World!\n"

Followed by:
cc -c HelloWorld.s
ld -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.o -e _start 
./HelloWorld

It is poorly documented, but ldr <reg>,=<label> doesn't work on MacOS when the label is in a different section of code.  You must use adrp/add.

It's not just a macOS issue, PC-relative addressing just only goes so far.

@fuz. On the Mac, it’s more than just distance. Code is signed, even when it’s not part of a shareable library. So the linker can’t deal with something that’s an unknown—even if small—distance away.

@FrankYellin I just tried your suggestion, but I still have the error of Bad system call: 22 in macos shell terminal.

And you ran the commands at the bottom?

I meant system call 12 not 22

Yes I did run those commands at the bottom

@FrankYellin Hm weird.  Should text and data be relocated together?  And how is this related to code signing?

@Salty4141 you're using the wrong syscall ABI. You need to use x16 and 4 for write and 1 for exit (exactly like Frank did). The YouTube video you saw was for Linux.

@fuz the ldr = syntax generates a pointer in the text segment. Pointers would need to be rebased at load time, but the text segment is r-x (and flipping it to rw- and back and then trying to execute it will get your process killed).

@Siguza Oh right, I had read this as adr, not ldr.  u

@Siguza also FrankYellin
I implemented what you both said and now it runs successfully, but it's not writing "Hello World!" to the terminal when it runs. I updated the code in the question to reflect what I currently have

Please use the exact code I gave you.  You cannot use adr.  You cannot use ldr -=.  For an address in a different section, you must use the two-instruction sequence that I gave you.  That's a well-known difference with MacOS.

I did and an error occured at the assembling stage. There an error with the adr call. Says error: unknown AArch64 fixup kind!

I don’t use “adr” in my code. So you must have miscopied. Just cut and paste my code into a file. Don’t try copying it by hand.

For the record, you can make the linker fix up two- or three-instruction sequences if possible with one of a few .loh directives, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76318308/2302862
